# What would make sense to use for measuring a 0-10V analog signal? (Arduino, ESP32, ESP8266 with ADS1115)

Tags: arduino, esp8266, esp32, adc

I'm trying to read in a 0-10V analog signal from a pressure gauge (Balzers SingleGauge TPG 251) with the help of an arduino nano. With a voltage divider I'm able to get to a 0-5V range to not damage my arduino. Sad thing is that the resolution of the integrated 10-bit ADC is pretty low (5000mV/1023 ~ 5mV steps) for my purposes. The pressure gauge can measure from 10e-11 mbar to 1000 mbar and will give a value from 0-10V accordingly. Through observations I've seen the display change values in this way:

- 1000 to 100 being in 10 steps = 91 numbers
- 100 to 1 in 0.1 steps = 991 numbers
- 9.9e-1 to 1e-2 = 99 numbers per decade (there are 11 decades --> 99*1 = 1089 numbers)

  - Total of 2171 separate analog steps (if the steps are linear).

This means that each analog step will be of 4.6 mV in a 0-10V range. Since I'm using a voltage devider the mV/step difference will be halved, reaching a 2.3 mV/step. This is obviously to low to resolve and so I need to use an 12- or 16-bit ADC. I decided to use a 16-bit ADC because why not have a better precision, right? I have bought the ADS1115 and I hope to be able to read the values a lot better and more precise (max 0.15mV). With the analog value I can then reversly get the pressure as a number.

The real problems come in now. I want to have the setup connected to the local wifi where people can look at the pressure. And I would also like to let them enter the value they want to be alerted on per email that they also enter.
I've seen this tutorial with an ESP32 (https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-email-alert-temperature-threshold/) where it's possible. So I'll try to follow through that with an ESP8266 nodeMCU.

I know this is a lot to take in and I hope somebody has an Idea how I can advance in this project. Here are some questions from my side:

1. Do I need both an arduino and a ESP8266 for this project? Since Arduinos analog range is from 0-5V and the ESPs analog range is from 0-1V, arduino can thus handle more. ESP would then just have the purpose of sending the email and web server stuff.
2. Is there a way to just use the ESP8266 and the ADS1115 and still read the analog values with a high precision? Or is it just not possible?
3. Any feedback what would make sense here? Maybe there is a way to do this that I've not yet googled.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 99% of this post is not necessary to your actual question. please value our time. also simply entering "ADS1115  ESP" into any websearch would have yielded plenty of tutorials and libraries. making your post completely obsolete.

Comment: I needed to see if my thought process would make sense for this situation. Thats why the long explanation. Otherwise there would be somebody who would need more information and I would need to write the whole idea anyway.

Comment: the question is off-topic here

Comment: Oh... Sorry. Where would it make most sense to post then?

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADS1115 has a I2C interface. Just hook it up to the ESP. There is no need for the Arduino nano.

Please read the datasheet of your ADC.

http://www.esp8266learning.com/ads1115-analog-to-digital-converter-and-esp8266.php